# Hashing for sparse bit vectors

Tags: algorithm, hash

Does anyone have any good intuition for a good hash function for a sparse bit vector?
To give a concrete example, say I want to hash a 4096 bit integer where the probability of each bit being 1 is 10%.

I want to get some compression in the hash. For example 4096 bits in and 32 bits out. This is just an example to illustrate what I am looking for. Of course, all answers are very much appreciated.

Comment: Please say what kind of hash you're looking for. In Java and .NET, hash codes (for hashtables etc) are 32 bit integers to start with - so the obvious answer would be to return the original value. I suspect that's not what you want, so more clarity would be welcome.

Comment: Maybe 32 bits was too small an example. Say it's 1024 bits, or some other larger value. I want to get some compression. So 32 bit in -> 32 bit out is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) help?

If the bit vector is 2^32 bits, then why not just use a 32 bit integer?

Comment: You may want to amend your statement "if the bit vector is 2^32 bits" ;]

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any idea of what to use for the hash functions for the Bloom Filter?

Comment: Say for a 32 bit integer (as per original edit), you could have a size 2^16 bit vector, and set bit n if integer n/(2^16) is set. Then if you want to know if x is in your original data, you know "yes or maybe" (never "no") if bit x/(2^16) is set. Works if the set is sparse and expensive to search.

Comment: Check out the book Programming Pearls for more info and ideas on squeezing data: <http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/>

Answer (score 0):

I would just hash the bits as usual by calling

```
hash<vector<bool>>(...)
```

if you're using C++0x, or else see boost::hash.